# changing base of a number to a given number

Tags: python

I must write a recursive function that gets a number(n) in the 10 base and converts it to a given number base(k) and return a list which its components are the final number digits,for example `f(5, 3)` must result `[1, 2]` which 5 in base 3 is 12, or `f(22, 3)` must result `[2, 1, 1]`.

Here's the code I tried:

```
def cb(n, k):
    b = []
    if n == 0:
        b.append(0)
    if n < k:
        b.append(n)
    if n == k:
        b.append(10)
    else:
        a = n // k
        b.append(n - ((n // k) * k))
        if a < k:
            b.append(a)
        else:
            cb(a, k)

    return b

print(cb(22, 3))
```

Actually I thought a lot on it but since I'm not so good at writing codes I couldn't go any further. I appreciate your help and modifications to my code .

Comment: Does it work? How do you know? What values does it work for?

Comment: nope my code doesn't work,and actually i can't make another way...

Comment: What does `else: cb(a, k)` do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you think in terms of recursion the base case is when `n < k` for which the answer is `n` and to get the last digit of the `n` you do `n%k` so the recusive case is `cb(n//k,k)+[n%k]`.

The code will look like this :

```
def cb(n, k):
    if n < k:
        return [n]
    else:
        return cb(n//k, k) + [n%k]

print(cb(22, 3))
```

Answer (score 2):

you were very close, the only thing that you needed to do was change:

```
    else:
        cb(a, k)
```

to:

```
    else:
        b.extend(cb(a, k))
```

however, your output is going to be:

```
>>> cb(22, 3)
[1, 1, 2]
```

which is the reverse of what you want, since 22 in base 3 is `211`. you can fix this by either reversing the list `[1,1,2][::-1] == [2,1,1]` or replace all your calls to `append` and your new call to `extend` to instead add at the beginning of the list like: `b.insert(0,element)` or `b = cb(a,k) + b`

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem is that you aren't doing anything with the results of the recursive call, so they never go in your list. I think you are also complicating this too much. Something like this should work:

```
def cb(n,k):
  if n > 0:
    q = n // k
    r = n - q * k
    b = cb(q, k)
    b.append(r)
  else:
    b = [0]

  if b[0] == 0 and len(b) > 1:
    b = b[1:]

  return b
```

I think if you don't do the last part, then you always get a 0 on the front? You could also simplify it further by just testing to see if it is less than the radix, which gives an even simpler solution

```
def cb(n,k):
  if n < k:
    return [n]
  else:
    q = n // k
    r = n - q * k
    b = cb(q, k)
    b.append(r)
    return b
```